# If QList instance is const, does it mean each element is constant?

Tags: c++, qlist

The following code fails to compile:

```
void func(const QList<int>& list){
  auto& elem = list[0];
}
```

The problem is I cannot bind const element to non-const reference. Following code works:

```
const auto& elem = list[0];
```

Can someone explain why passing a list as `const` makes all element to be `const`?

Comment: If you could modify elements of the list it wouldn't be very `const`, would it? C++ compound objects often try to mimic the default behavour of a `struct`, that is, if the object is `const`, the elements of that object are also `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain why passing a list as `const` makes all element to be `const`?

This is the semantics that standard containers are following. Here's the reason I can see:

```
const int arr1 = {10, 20};
arr1[0] = 40; // Error. Elements of arr1 cannot be modified.

const std::vector<int> arr2 = {10, 20};
arr2[0] = 40; // Same semantics. Error. Elements of arr2 cannot be modified.
```

Extending that logic to `QList`, the elements of a `QList` are `const` if the `QList` is a `const`.

Comment: The behavior is apparent, my question is why this is the case? any reference to standard or any logical reason, or at least any problem when not following it?

Comment: They are following the semantics of the built in arrays and standard containers, which makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto& elem = list[0];
```

This means you are assigning the value of `list[0]` to `elem` by reference, that can alter the value of your `list[0]`.

```
void func(const QList<int>& list)
```

You have passed list as const which means `func` is not supposed to alter the list.

Below code will work:

```
auto elem = list[0]; //This will work, as it will create copy
const auto& elem = list[0]; //will not allow to change the value
```

Comment: I passed the list as const, but the members of that list are not const (or not explicitly at least)

Comment: @Rakib As Mankarse commented, if you can modify the elements of list, then how it can be const?